# Firebase check for existing user in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have VC where by I am creating a new user and adding to firebase. The user inserts no problem into the database but I am having trouble checking if a user with the same name already exists. I have tried using various query statements within firebase but not getting any joy. Does anyone know how I can modify my code to accomplish this? here it is :-

```
 @IBAction func submitUsername(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let user = usernameTxtField.text where user != "" {

       let username = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.childByAppendingPath("username")

       username.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {  snap in

            if let usernameDoesNotExist = snap.value as? NSNull {
              let currentUser = DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.childByAppendingPath("username")
              self.usernameTxtField.text = user
              currentUser.setValue(user)
            }
       })

       dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        showAlert("Username Needed", msg: "please choose a username")
    } 
}
```

and the firebase data structure

```
"users" : {
    "000591b6-ba88-4670-9cb7-edd79c273eab" : {
      "newuser" : "added to FB",
      "provider" : "password"
    },
    "05551c90-27fe-4969-b45d-279a72583857" : {
      "newuser" : "added to FB",
      "provider" : "password"
    },
    "0bbff1b0-681a-4fef-adc0-c4779a4b2100" : {
      "provider" : "password",
      "testing" : "emailtest",
      "username" : "richy446"
    },
    "12f35e7a-2430-49b3-a287-f7b1daf6a121" : {
      "newuser" : "added to FB",
      "provider" : "password",
      "username" : "richy445"
    },
    "15a45560-cc81-4c2d-bb59-b8ce6b125d68" : {
      "provider" : "password",
      "testing" : "emailtest",
      "username" : "richy445"
    },
    "1c135936-6dd0-4189-bcd7-e8036e9736f9" : {
      "newuser" : "added to FB",
      "provider" : "password"
    },
    "21591e29-f083-452c-b74f-cc567cecb183" : {
      "newuser" : "added to FB",
      "provider" : "password"
    },
    "8b385aa7-0e80-426b-a385-5b3317c894d0" : {
      "newuser" : "added to FB",
      "provider" : "password",
      "username" : "richy445"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to check to see if the user name exists in Firebase (i.e. login credentials) or are you asking how to see if the user name exists in your /users node? Also, posting your Firebase structure (as text, no images, please) helps us understand your structure and clarify's your question.

Comment: mainDict -> posts -> users   -> username     that is that structure of firebase, within username , I want to add a user to the database which I'm doing but but if a username is already taken I don't want to add a user (will probably display a message alert of some sort)

Comment: That's not really a good structure to store usernames. The child nodes of /users should be the uid, and a child of that should be a username: "the user name" as a key:value pair. It's probably going to cause other issues with the users node being a child of the posts node. Can you please update your question with your Firebase Structure? That will keep us from having to retype and will also clarify the question and the issue.

Comment: just added it, looking to add the username field once I have checked if the name is available.

Comment: Close... Please post as text (per my above comment), not an image so we don't have to retype it. When you post as text, it's searchable (images aren't) and will help others in the future.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do that, the pic above is how my data is structured. i just need to know how to check if a user already exists in my database before adding the username ? can anyone else assist with this at all. Not sure what other information I can provide its all here. I can see PER YOUR ABOVE COMMENT WHAT YOU ARE ASKING FOR but surely you can see from the screenshot what I am trying to accomplish? all I'm asking for is a little help

Comment: Firebase Dashboard  and click the Export button. Screenshots are evil. :-)

Comment: Firebase will return an error if the username already exists when you attempt to create the user.

Comment: its just posting as a mess :-( firebase at the moment the way I have done it above is allowing me to just choose the same username so Im obviously doing something wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to checking for duplicate data. The Firebase structure you have seems a little inconsistent so structuring it like this may be easier

```
"000591b6-ba88-4670-9cb7-edd79c273eab" : {
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "password" : "password"
    },
"05551c90-27fe-4969-b45d-279a72583857" : {
      "email" : "test2@test.com",
      "password" : "password"
    },
```

1) Let Firebase do the work for you.

When creating a user, Firebase will return an error if the username (email) already exists. Using this method will prevent random data being written to your firebase until they account is created in Firebase.

```
myRootRef.createUser(email, password: pw, withValueCompletionBlock: { error, result in

    if error != nil {
        self.errMsgField.stringValue = "email/username in use, try again"

    } else {
        let uid = result["uid"] as! String //the uid of the new user
        print("user created as  \(uid)")
        self.storedDataInUserNode(email, password:pw)
        self.authUserWithAuthData( email, password: pw ) //auth the user
        // and proceed in starting up the app
    }
})
```

2) Checking for existing data in Firebase.

While the first method stops data from being written in the first place, if you want to check for duplicate data in general, here's a pattern:

```
let userName = the userName or email the user entered
let usersRef = Firebase(url:"https://test.firebaseio.com/users")
usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("\(userName!)")
            .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found)") //didnt find it, ok to proceed

        } else {
            print(snapshot.value) //found it, stop!
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a method on DataSnapshot named .exists() that you can you can call like this.
Updated for Swift 4.

```
struct ModelUser {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    init(data: DataSnapshot) {
        // do init stuff
    }
}

func isUserRegistered(with id: String, completion: @escaping (_ exists: Bool, _ user: ModelUser?) -> ()) {
    DatabaseReference.users.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            // user is already in our database
            completion(true, ModelUser(data: snapshot))
        } else {
            // not in database
            completion(false, nil)
        }
    }
}
```